# echo variable from a string

Tags: php

I had created this function that simply accepts some arguments to take some information from a table, and echoes the result mixed with some HTML that is passed with args

functions.php

```
function loop_show($conn,$table,$div){
        $string_query="select * from $table";
        $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$string_query);
        while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "$div";
            
        }
}
```

when calling the function from another page

index.php

```
<?php loop_show($conn,"projects","<div>Hello $result[name] , Your age is $result[age]</div>") ?>
```

the problem is that I don't have $result variable in index.php but I just want to tell the function that it should echo the $result in specified place

Comment: It looks like you're looking for template software. There are frameworks for this.

Comment: By what magic should `$result` be included inside `$div`? Your `$result` is already parsed in the `loop_show` function call, and by all measures should be giving you warnings, of undefined `$result`, or if you happened to have it defined, of invalid use of array keys (that evaluate as constants if not 'quoted').

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function for this.

```
function loop_show($conn,$table,$divfun){
    $string_query="select * from $table";
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,$string_query);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo $divfun($result);
    }
}

loop_show($conn,"projects", 
    function($result) { 
        return "<div>Hello $result[name] , Your age is $result[age]</div>";
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks it's Working and that's exaclty what i want .